# Replicate network plugins without having to configure it for each subsite?

Tags: multisite, customization

I was wondering if there is a simple way to replicate my configurations for all the subsites once i have activated a network plugin without having to go thru each and configure it manually ?

- Upgrade a set or single network plugin(s) with the same configuration to all subsites

Comment: *@Prix* Which specific settings are you looking to replicate?

Comment: Well it is not really a specific setting but let's say you have installed the plugin nextgen gallery for network and you have 30 subsites you would have to go thru each configurating the options you want for it instead i just want it to have the same rules as the main site has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to write some custom stuff to copy settings across blogs. Currently I've got a plugin with two textareas:

1. A read-only box with a [base64 encoded](https://www.php.net/base64-encode) [serialized](https://www.php.net/serialize) string of all the blog options (`wp_options`) I care about (in this case, widgets, sidebars, and options from [a specific plugin](http://code.google.com/p/9spot/))
2. A field that can accept the same encoded string copied from another blog

So, I don't know of a good way besides dumping the data via WordPress's `get_option()` or SQL queries, and loading the data back in on another database.

Comment: thanks for the input, i did my own plugin aswell it has a list of all the blogs avaiable and you can just select to which subsites and what plugins you want to replicate and it does it all.

Answer (score 1):

They only way I know of to do this is a paid plugin.

Comment: I saw that one it was a ripe off for such a simple thing, but thanks.

Comment: It's mine. :) Most people think it's too cheap.

Comment: if it was about 5 or 10 bucks i would have considered buying it but since it won't be used too much and i am also able to code it, it wouldnt justify paying the price atleast not for myself i didnt mean to be mean or anything alike in the previous comment so i hope you didnt take that, that way and thanks for the recommendation i did take a look on it and it seemed nice.